# Get Message After Task Completion Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

How to access the message printed after every task completion in the script?
(Green highlighted)

[image]

Comment: Where do you want to access it from? From a test teardown? From a listener? From an external script?

Comment: I want to get this message in case the task fails and add it to a CSV file. It is supposed to be in the same single robot file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the error message from a test teardown in the [automatic variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#automatic-variables) `${TEST MESSAGE}`.

You can use the automatic variable `${TEST STATUS}` to know if the test passed or failed.

You can use the `OperatingSystem` keyword [Append to file](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Append%20To%20File) to append failure messages  to a file.

In a comment you said this needs to work for tasks. Here is a complete example with two failing and one passing test.

```
*** Settings ***
Library        OperatingSystem
Test Teardown  Append test message to csv

*** Keywords ***
Append test message to csv
    run keyword if  $TEST_STATUS == "FAIL"
    ...  Append to file  failures.csv   ${TEST NAME}, ${TEST MESSAGE}\n

*** Tasks ***
Passing task
    pass execution  life is good

Failing task 1
    [Documentation]  adds "Failing task 1, Variable '${no var}' not found." to csv file
    Should be equal  ${no var}  whatever

Failing task 2
    [Documentation]  adds "Failing task 2, bummer" to csv file
    fail  bummer
```

This is an imperfect solution since it's possible for the test name or test message to have a command in it. You should probably write a keyword in python that uses the csv module to properly quote the values, but this shows the basic concept of how to access the data for failing tests.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but it does not seem to work.. I am working on Task, this fits for Test

Comment: @UtsavTalwar: this will work for tasks exactly the same as for tests.

Comment: @UtsavTalwar: I've updated the answer with a fully functioning example based on tasks.